# Which image formats can be resized in JavaFX

Tags: java, image, javafx, resize, image-resizing

There are about 100 jpeg & png color images used in our JavaFX-built desktop app which, when the window is resized, become stretched and blurry so I'd like to have all the graphics remade in a format that will allow them to be dynamically resized without losing quality. What image format or procedure should be used to do this?

Currently, each image is simply in an ImageView and resized as follows, but I'm open to other suggestions:

```
if(isSmall){
    Rectangle2D visualBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    double sh = visualBounds.getHeight();
    Scale scale = new Scale(sh, sh, 0, 0);
    root.getTransforms().setAll(scale);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been mentioned SVG is probably the way to go for you. JavaFX does not support SVG directly but you can find support here
[javafxsvg](https://github.com/codecentric/javafxsvg) and here [svg-to-fxml-converter](https://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2012/08/22/svg-to-fxml-converter-as-commandline-util/) for example.

Comment: Thanks. I'll either use this library or wait for Java 9 to provide multi-resolution images.

Answer (score 0):

You can't resize an image to be bigger than it is without it getting blurry for most common formats.  Instead make sure your images are big enough so you only need to downscale them.

The only format I ever heard of that could upscale further was using fractal compression, but AFAIK it is not in common use.

Comment: Do you mean you can't resize an image…in JavaFX? There are image formats that can be enlarged without losing quality (e.g. vector graphics). I'd like to know what others do in my situation.

Comment: Sure, vectors you can resize, but you mentioned JPEG and PNG.  Perhaps you want to try SVG files.

Comment: Right, I should clarify. I'm looking to have all the graphics remade in a new format and am looking for suggestions/want to make sure they work with JavaFX.

Comment: There's basic support for SVG paths that will scale, but not full SVG.

Comment: However, it should be possible to render SVG's onto a Canvas at any size you like, just not directly with JavaFX.  It would require using a standard SVG library and adapting it to draw to a Canvas.

Comment: Thanks. I'll either use the above library or wait for Java 9 to provide multi-resolution images.